# Convergence test for positive series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the series  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (n+1) a_n^2$ converges. Does it imply the series
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty  a_n
$$
is also converges?

Comment: What do you mean by "$<\infty$"?

Comment: @Jacob That it converges to a finite number.

Comment: I mean less than infinity or what is the same that the series converge

Answer (score 1):

Try $$a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)\log(n+1)}.$$

Comment: lol, beat me by a couple seconds... Will delete mine...

Comment: mmm. I really don't know what to do with that

Comment: @JORGEBARRERA: they are suggesting you that you prove that for such $a_n$ you have $\sum(n+1)a_n^2<\infty$ and $\sum a_n=\infty$.

Comment: @JORGE BARRERA Comparison test shows the first converges and the same test shows the second diverges, hence your hypothesis do not imply $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_n$ converges